# How do I fix this error? error: cannot find symbol Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));

Tags: android

I have an error that says:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));
               ^
  symbol:   method setData(Object)
  location: variable Vholder of type ViewHolder
```

How do I fix these?

Here is the code: This is my Adapter class for my grid layout. I do not know why it is not working.

```
public class TrackAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    ArrayList mValues;
    Context mContext;
    protected ItemListener mListener;

    public TrackAdapter(Context context, ArrayList values, ItemListener itemListener) {

        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        mListener=itemListener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        TrackData data;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {

            super(v);

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        }

        public void setData(TrackData data) {
            this.data = data;

            textView.setText(data.text);
            imageView.setImageResource(data.icon);
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(data.gridBGColor));

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemClick(data);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TrackAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.makati_recycler_grid_track, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    **public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder Vholder, int position) {
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));
    }**

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mValues.size();
    }

    public interface ItemListener {
        void onItemClick(TrackData data);
    }
}
```

or here is the line

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder Vholder, int position) {
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));
    }
```

Comment: This is basic reference variable stuff . You need to cast it because what you are getting is `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` .  Use `((TrackAdapter.ViewHolder)Vholder).setData(mValues.get(position));` . For another fix If you have only one View Holder then you can just provide type when extending `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackAdapter.ViewHolder>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend your TrackAdapter with RecyclerView Type. ie.

```
public class TrackAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< ViewHolder >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast **RecyclerView.ViewHolder** to **TrackAdapter.ViewHolder** like this:

```
if (Vholder instanceof TrackAdapter.ViewHolder){

 ((TrackAdapter.ViewHolder)Vholder).setData(mValues.get(position));
}
```